# What kind of insurance would cover death/disability for organ donors?

Tags: insurance, india, life-insurance, health-insurance

Let's say I'm going to be a living donor for a relative. I'm about to willingly undergo major surgery with known (albeit low) risks. I will be taking on significant debt to pay for the whole thing. I would, therefore, want to go in with the knowledge that if I don't make it out alive at least my debts are paid off and my family is taken care of.

Are there any insurance companies (India-specific) that would cover this kind of risk? What kind of policy would it be? (life insurance? medical?)

Comment: As JoeTaxpayer said, you are amazingly generous and I hope that all will turn out well and that there will be no need for the insurance company to pay a death benefit.  That being said, many insurance policies explicitly exclude coverage if you participate in certain activities that increase your risk of dying. A common joke is that death during lion-taming is not covered. Whether donating an organ constitutes participating in a hazardous activity that is excluded from coverage is something that you need to look into. As Joe says, there may be waiting periods too that will not suit you.

Comment: Does the other party have insurance? In the US the procedure would be covered by the recipients insurance. I don't know how that translates into life and disability coverage.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Due to various reasons, the recipients insurance has rejected all claims so far that have led up to the diagnosis for a transplant. I am not optimistic on whether they will cover the transplant itself.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I suppose you're right. I was hoping that there would be some way to get around the increased risk. Perhaps by agreeing to a higher premium, or paying the full premium amount up-front.

Comment: @Ragesh This may not be super helpful, but I have to say that I have been in that sort of a situation, so Respect for opting to be a donor. I believe this will fall under medical insurance and will mostly have to be negotiated first-hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the chance of a plane crash is very low, and the insurance one buys for a two day trip very overpriced for the risk, I always hear "tell that to the families of flt xxx that crashed last week."
So, I understand your request. Life insurance is tough. You usually have to die to collect. A complete disability or long term illness isn't enough.

This is one of those times I suggest talking to an insurance agent, both medical and life. Explain your intention, as it's best to be honest. If I buy life insurance, there may be some exclusions or waiting period, after all, a suicidal person may very well have the thought to first buy a huge policy for his family. By explaining the reason and timing of your purchase you can make sure you have the right product.

(by the way, I wish you well, it's a kind, amazing, thing you are about to do.)

Comment: Thanks, Joe. I guess you're right -- I really should be talking to an agent about this as it's a complicated situation.

Comment: @Ragesh - When you are recovered, and back on line, please come back and update to share how you are doing. This is one question where I hope to get an update. And to hear that you and the recipient are both doing great. I wish you well, sir!